# Multiple Choice Custom Field Not saved on creation of new contribution

Tags: custom-fields

I am running CiviCRM 4.4.4 on WP 3.6.1

This is a problem with entering new contributions.

I have a custom field tied to a multiple choice menu.
The same menu is used for 4 different custom fields,
one of which is required.

If you do not fill in the required field an error is generated upon submit.

If you select one of the options, and submit a valid contribution,
then immediately view the contribution, the fields tied to this 
menu are empty.  (including the required one)

The final piece to the puzzle.  If I go back in and edit the contribution
and re-enter the data, the second time it sticks.

What could be causing something like this?

Comment: Also, the fields are of type Autocomplete-Select

Answer (score 1):

Could you try to reproduce this bug on the [4.4 Demo Site](http://wp44.demo.civicrm.org/) by creating a similar custom field/contribution setup? If it's a bug there then you could report it to the LTS team (although noncritical bug fixes for older versions don't get high priority).

You could also try to reproduce it on the [4.6 Demp Site](http://wp46.demo.civicrm.org/) which would be a good idea for 2 reasons:

1. If it is still a bug in 4.6 it will get more attention.
2. If it is not still a bug in 4.6 you could solve your problem by upgrading :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in LTS.  I upgraded to 4.4.16 on the latest version of WP (4.2.2).  It is easy to reproduce.  Create a custom field set for Contributions, create a custom field (multiple-choice,autocomplete) create a few choices, make it required.  I made it searchable to match my application.  Enter a new contribution, view it, not there.

I then upgraded again to 4.6.4.  used the same test.  This time the data is preserved.  This is not a minor bug in LTS from my perspective, because you don't make a field required unless that data is important.  So for this particular field we have huge gaping holes in our data.

In case anyone is having a similar problem in 4.4.16, it is fixed in 4.6.4.